# How to bind click and change event for checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am adding some checkbox to the page through ajax how to bind the click and change function for these checkboxes
my script is here

```
$(document).delegate("#filterOptions input[name=inNeedAmountRange]").bind("click change", function () {
    var elementValue = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('checked : ' + elementValue);
    }
} else {
    alert('Not checked :' + elementValue);
}
});
```

Comment: The answers below both suggest using the .on method, but that will depend on the version of jQuery you are using. Are you using jQuery 1.7 or later?

Comment: @AnthonyVeach yes I am using jQuery 1.7 only

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Nnzx4/)</kbd>

```
$(document).on("click change", "#filterOptions input[name=inNeedAmountRange]", function () {
    var elementValue = this.value;
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('checked : ' + elementValue);
    } else {
  // ^ remove extra }
        alert('Not checked :' + elementValue);
    }
});
```

---

[Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 3):

Try: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on("change click", ""#filterOptions input[name=inNeedAmountRange]", function() {
    //do something
});
```

You can replace document with any static container.